# Tensorflow Object Detection API and Precision Recall curves

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a small question. I have noticed that there is a new plugin for the Tensorboard application for directly [plot PR-Curves in Tensorboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/pr_curve).

Does anyone know if there is already an integration of this new feature into the TF Object Detection API? I already implemented my own PR-Curves that will be shown in the image section of Tensorboard but the native integration seems to be more useful.

Thank you for your help.